# JQGrid not displaying values for some columns and for others are displayed correctly

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I am using Spring MVC, Hibernate, MySQL, JSP and JQGrid for my web application. While trying to implement one page, I am experiencing strange behavior as narrated below:

1. JSON Data is passed to the JSP is correct and is valid in all the columns
2. However, out of 28 columns, data is displayed in 21 columns correctly, but in 7 columns data is not displayed at all. These 7 columns are first 4 and other 3 are in the middle.
3. Relevent part of js-for-acctmst.js file are as below:

   ```
    grid.jqGrid({ 
        datatype: 'json', 
        mtype: 'GET', 
        height: 'auto',
        url:'/NioERPJ/admin/acctmstmgmt/',
        editurl:'/NioERPJ/admin/acctmstmgmt/edit',
        colNames:['Company Code','A/c Code','A/c Description','BA Code', 'Sched', 'Rel. Code', 'Header', 'BPTA', 'Perc.', 'T_O_AC', 'Op.Cr.', 'Op.Dr.', 'Sgn', 'Fnd', 'Ledger', 
                   'LedgerSum', 'DFlag', 'Tran Dr.', 'Tran Cr.', 'OutField', 'Gross', 'Net', 'SFlag', 'SaleCD', 'Add3', 'DateOP Dr.', 'DateOP Cr.', 'Username'],
           colModel:[
               {name:'co_code',index:'co_code',editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:"/NioERPJ/admin/acctmstmgmt/listCmps"},formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'acc_code',index:'acc_code', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:7}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'acc_des',index:'acc_des', width:100, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:100}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'ba_code',index:'ba_code', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:8}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'sched',index:'sched', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'rel_code',index:'rel_code', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'header',index:'header', width:50, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
               {name:'bpta',index:'bpta', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'perc',index:'perc', width:50, template : numberTemplate},
               {name:'t_o_ac',index:'t_o_ac', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:1}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'op_cr',index:'op_cr', width:50, template : numberTemplate},
               {name:'op_dr',index:'op_dr', width:50, template : numberTemplate},
               {name:'sgn',index:'sgn', width:100, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'fnd',index:'fnd', width:50, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
               {name:'ledger',index:'ledger', width:50, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
               {name:'ledgersum',index:'ledgersum', width:50, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
               {name:'dflag',index:'dflag', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'tran_dr',index:'tran_dr', width:50, template : numberTemplate},
               {name:'tran_cr',index:'tran_cr', width:50, template : numberTemplate},
               {name:'out_field',index:'out_field', width:50, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
               {name:'gross',index:'gross', width:50, template : numberTemplate},
               {name:'net',index:'net', width:50, template : numberTemplate},
               {name:'sflag',index:'sflag', width:50, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
               {name:'salecd',index:'salecd', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true,number:true}, editoptions:{size:10}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'add3',index:'add3', width:100, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
               {name:'dateop_dr',index:'dateop_dr', width:50, template : numberTemplate},
               {name:'dateop_cr',index:'dateop_cr', width:50, template : numberTemplate},
               {name:'username',index:'username', width:100, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}}
           ],
        gridview: true,
        toolbar: [false, "bottom"],
        pager: $('#pager'), 
        rowNum:15, 
        rowList:[10,20,30], 
        sortname: 'acc_code', 
        sortorder: "asc", 
        viewrecords: true,
        altRows: false, 
        autowidth:true, 
        shrinkToFit:false,
        forceFit:true,
        jsonReader : {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",  
            repeatitems: false
           },
   ```

   The controller file 'Acctmstcontroller.java' is as below:

   ```
   package com.nej.controller;

       @Controller
      @RequestMapping(value={"/admin/acctmstmgmt"})
      public class AcctMstController {
   @Autowired
   private AcctMstService acctmstService;

   @Autowired
   private CompanyMstService companymstService;

   @RequestMapping(value="/open")         
   public ModelAndView opAcctmstmgmt(){
       ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
   model.setViewName("/admin/acctmstmgmt");
   return model;
   } 

   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")         
   public @ResponseBody  AcctMstResponse getAll(
           @RequestParam("_search") Boolean search,
           @RequestParam(value="filters", required=false) String filters,
           @RequestParam(value = "rows", required=false) Integer rows, 
           @RequestParam(value = "page", required=false) Integer page, 
           @RequestParam(value = "sidx", required=false) String sidx, 
           @RequestParam(value = "sord", required=false) String sord, 
           HttpServletRequest request) {

       if (search == true) {
           return getFilteredRecords(filters, rows,page, sidx, sord);
   }


        List<AcctMst> list = null;
        list = acctmstService.getAcctMsts(rows,page, sidx, sord);
        AcctMstResponse response = new AcctMstResponse();
        response.setRows(list);
        int count = acctmstService.getNoOfRecords();
        int total = count%rows == 0 ? (int)Math.ceil(count/rows) : (int)Math.ceil(count/rows)+1;
        response.setTotal(total);
        response.setRecords(count);
        response.setPage(page);
        return response;
    }

   public AcctMstResponse getFilteredRecords(String filters, Integer rows, Integer page, String sidx, String sord) {

           List<AcctMst> list = null;
           list = acctmstService.searchAcctMsts(filters,rows,page, sidx, sord);

           AcctMstResponse response = new AcctMstResponse();
           response.setRows(list);
           int count = acctmstService.getNoOfRecords();
           int total = count%rows == 0 ? (int)Math.ceil(count/rows) : (int)Math.ceil(count/rows)+1;
           response.setTotal(total);
           response.setRecords(count);
           response.setPage(page);
           return response;
   }

    @RequestMapping(value="/edit")
    public ModelAndView doEdit(HttpServletRequest request) {

       Byte co_code = 0;
       String acc_code = null;
       String acc_des = null;
       String ba_code = null;
       String sched = null;
       String rel_code = null;
       boolean header = false;
       String bpta = null;
       double perc = 0.00d;
       String t_o_ac = null;
       double op_cr = 0.00d;
       double op_dr = 0.00d;
       String sgn = null;
       boolean fnd = false;
       boolean ledger = false;
       boolean ledgersum = false;
       String dflag = null;
       double tran_dr = 0.00d;
       double tran_cr = 0.00d;
       boolean out_field = false;
       double gross = 0.00d;
       double net = 0.00d;
       boolean sflag = false;
       String salecd = null;
       double add3 = 0.00d;
       double dateop_dr = 0.00d;
       double dateop_cr = 0.00d;
       String username = null;
       String oper = null;


        Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()){
            String s = paramNames.nextElement();

            if("co_code".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                co_code = Byte.parseByte(request.getParameter("co_code"));
            }else if("acc_code".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                acc_code = request.getParameter("acc_code");
            }else if("acc_des".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                acc_des = request.getParameter("acc_des");
            }else if("ba_code".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                ba_code = request.getParameter("ba_code");
            }else if("sched".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                sched = request.getParameter("sched");
            }else if("rel_code".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                rel_code = request.getParameter("rel_code");
            }else if("header".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                header = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("header"));
            }else if("bpta".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                bpta = request.getParameter("bpta");
            }else if("perc".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                perc = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("perc"));
            }else if("t_o_ac".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                t_o_ac = request.getParameter("t_o_ac");
            }else if("op_cr".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                op_cr = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("op_cr"));
            }else if("op_dr".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                op_dr = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("op_dr"));
            }else if("sgn".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                sgn = request.getParameter("sgn");
            }else if("fnd".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                fnd = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("fnd"));
            }else if("ledger".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                ledger = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("ledger"));
            }else if("ledgersum".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                ledgersum = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("ledgersum"));
            }else if("dflag".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                dflag = request.getParameter("dflag");
            }else if("tran_dr".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                tran_dr = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("tran_dr"));
            }else if("tran_cr".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                tran_cr = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("tran_cr"));
            }else if("out_field".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                out_field = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("out_field"));
            }else if("gross".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                gross = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("gross"));
            }else if("net".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                net = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("net"));
            }else if("sflag".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                sflag = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("sflag"));
            }else if("salecd".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                salecd = request.getParameter("salecd");
            }else if("add3".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                add3 = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("add3"));
            }else if("dateop_dr".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                dateop_dr = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("dateop_dr"));
            }else if("dateop_cr".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                dateop_cr = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("dateop_cr"));
            }else if("username".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                username = request.getParameter("username");
            }else if("oper".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                oper = request.getParameter("oper");
            }
        }
       Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if("edit".equalsIgnoreCase(oper)){
            AcctMst acctmst = new AcctMst();
            acctmst.setAcccode(acc_code);
            acctmst.setAccdes(acc_des);
            acctmst.setAdd3(add3);
            acctmst.setBacode(ba_code);
            acctmst.setBpta(bpta);
            acctmst.setCocode(co_code);
            acctmst.setDateopcr(dateop_cr);
            acctmst.setDateopdr(dateop_dr);
            acctmst.setDflag(dflag);
            acctmst.setFnd(fnd);
            acctmst.setGross(gross);
            acctmst.setHeader(header);
            acctmst.setLedger(ledger);
            acctmst.setLedgersum(ledgersum);
            acctmst.setNet(net);
            acctmst.setOpcr(op_cr);
            acctmst.setOpdr(op_dr);
            acctmst.setOutfield(out_field);
            acctmst.setPerc(perc);
            acctmst.setRelcode(rel_code);
            acctmst.setSalecd(salecd);
            acctmst.setSched(sched);
            acctmst.setSflag(sflag);
            acctmst.setSgn(sgn);
            acctmst.setToac(t_o_ac);
            acctmst.setTrancr(tran_cr);
            acctmst.setTrandr(tran_dr);
            acctmst.setUsername(username);
            acctmstService.updateAcctMst(acctmst);
        }else if("add".equalsIgnoreCase(oper)){
            AcctMst acctmst = acctmstService.getAcctMst(co_code, acc_code);
            if(acctmst == null){
               acctmst = new AcctMst();
               acctmst.setCocode(co_code);
               acctmst.setAcccode(acc_code);
               acctmst.setAccdes(acc_des);
               acctmst.setBacode(ba_code);
               acctmst.setSched(sched);
               acctmst.setRelcode(rel_code);
               acctmst.setHeader(header);
               acctmst.setBpta(bpta);
               acctmst.setPerc(perc);
               acctmst.setToac(t_o_ac);
               acctmst.setOpcr(op_cr);
               acctmst.setOpdr(op_dr);
               acctmst.setSgn(sgn);
               acctmst.setFnd(fnd);
               acctmst.setLedger(ledger);
               acctmst.setLedgersum(ledgersum);
               acctmst.setDflag(dflag);
               acctmst.setTrandr(tran_dr);
               acctmst.setTrancr(tran_cr);
               acctmst.setOutfield(out_field);
               acctmst.setGross(gross);
               acctmst.setNet(net);
               acctmst.setSflag(sflag);
               acctmst.setSalecd(salecd);
               acctmst.setAdd3(add3);
               acctmst.setDateopdr(dateop_dr);
               acctmst.setDateopcr(dateop_cr);
               acctmst.setUsername(username);
               acctmstService.saveAcctMst(acctmst);
            }else{
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }else if("del".equalsIgnoreCase(oper)){
            acctmstService.deleteAcctMst(co_code, acc_code);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("admin/acctmstmgmt",model);
    }
   ```

I am not able to resolve the issue of why some columns are  not displayed in JQGrid? pl. help.

I am adding following debug output from the apache log

> DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter -
>   com.nej.acctmst.model.AcctMst{rel_code=2, tran_dr=2.0, perc=2.0,
>   bpta=2, dateop_cr=2.0, acc_des=Test - 2, out_field=true, sflag=true,
>   sgn=2, net=2.0, fnd=true, op_cr=2.0, add3=2.0, ledger=true, dflag=2,
>   gross=2.0, tran_cr=2.0, ledgersum=true, salecd=2, dateop_dr=2.0,
>   sched=2, header=false, op_dr=2.0, t_o_ac=2, ba_code=2,
>   username=Test-2} 18:39:23.163 [http-apr-8080-exec-25] DEBUG
>   o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter -
>   com.nej.acctmst.model.AcctMst{rel_code=1, tran_dr=1.0, perc=1.0,
>   bpta=1, dateop_cr=1.0, acc_des=Test Account, out_field=true,
>   sflag=false, sgn=1, net=1.0, fnd=true, op_cr=1.0, add3=1.0,
>   ledger=true, dflag=1, gross=1.0, tran_cr=1.0, ledgersum=true,
>   salecd=1, dateop_dr=1.0, sched=1, header=true, op_dr=1.0, t_o_ac=1,
>   ba_code=1, username=Test}

I have installed Fiddler and found the following output for JSON

```
{"rows":[
{"sched":"1","header":true,"bpta":"1","perc":1.0,"sgn":"1","fnd":true,"ledger":true,
"ledgersum":true,"dflag":"1","gross":1.0,"net":1.0,"sflag":false,"salecd":"1",
"add3":1.0,"username":"Test","opdr":1.0,"opcr":1.0,"toac":"1","dateopdr":1.0,
"acccode":"1","cocode":1,"accdes":"Test Account","bacode":"1","dateopcr":1.0,
"trancr":1.0,"outfield":true,"trandr":1.0,"relcode":"1"},
{"sched":"2","header":false,"bpta":"2","perc":2.0,"sgn":"2","fnd":true,"ledger":true,
"ledgersum":true,"dflag":"2","gross":2.0,"net":2.0,"sflag":true,"salecd":"2",
"add3":2.0,"username":"Test-2","opdr":2.0,"opcr":2.0,"toac":"2","dateopdr":2.0,
"acccode":"2","cocode":2,"accdes":"Test - 2","bacode":"2","dateopcr":2.0,
"trancr":2.0,"outfield":true,"trandr":2.0,"relcode":"2"}
],
"total":1,
"records":2,
"page":1
}
```

It appears from the output that order of the fields has changed and also name of the fields are not the same as in colModel (in some fields underscore has been removed). Is my diagnosis correct?

Comment: You should include test data returned from `url:'/NioERPJ/admin/acctmstmgmt/'` (1-2 rows would be enough). By the way if the data returned from the server don't contain any HTML fragments then I recommend you to use `autoencode: true` option additionally. You can dramatically reduce the size and improve readability of `colModel` if you would use more `template` and `cmTemplete`. All `index` properties can be removed from `colModel`. `jsonReader` can be removed too or be reduced to `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}`

Comment: @Oleg I have added log file output. I need to give url : '/NioERPJ/admin/acctmstmgmt/open/', to open the page. I am not able to post image of the output as my points are less than 10.

Comment: Do you can use the debug output which you posted as input instead of `url : '/NioERPJ/admin/acctmstmgmt/open/'`? I'm not. You can for example use free [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool of Developer Tools of Chrome/IE/Firefox to see HTTP traffic. You will see the exact JSON response from `'/NioERPJ/admin/acctmstmgmt/open/`. One can save the data in text file and to use the path to the file instead of `'/NioERPJ/admin/acctmstmgmt/open/`. In the way one can reproduce the problem. You can include only 2 rows of data from the real response.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for suggesting improvements. I will implement it ASAP.

Comment: What I mean that you describe the problem which you have **with specific data**. It's very difficult to find the reason of the problem just reading of JavaScript which you posted. Moreover some problems exists only in combination with the input data. So much more effective is to have **the demo which reproduces the problem and which can be debugged**.  You can consider to create JSFiddle demo. Look at [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/ntfw57zm/5/) which shows how to use Echo service to create demo with `datatype: "json"` in JSFiddle.

Comment: @Oleg Again thanks. I have installed Fiddler and get the JSON output, whichI have appended to the main text. It primarily seems that their is field name mismatch between colModel and Spring MVC response.

Comment: @Oleg But not able to understand, why underscore character has been removed from the field names?

Comment: I don't use Spring MVC myself, but you need just change the values of `name` properties in jqGrid to solve the problem.

Comment: I would recommend you additionally to add `width: 50` to `numberTemplate` and uses `cmTemplate: {editable:true, width:100}` or `cmTemplate: {editable:true, width:50}`. It seems that introduction of one more template `var requiredTemplate = {editrules:{required:true}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}}` could have sense for many of your columns too. It will make `colModel` smaller and more readable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

With the extensive help and guidance from @Oleg, I could arrive at a conclusion that JSON data passed to my jsp file was not correctly formed. The field names were in different order as well as underscore character has been removed from them. This is the reason why some fields were not displayed in my .jsp file.